# Symfony Entity Type, No lazy load

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I created a symfony entity form-type and used a QueryBuilder to get the entities.

My Querybuilder looks like this:

```
 $qb = $this
            ->em
            ->getRepository('Namespace\Entity\Domain\Nic')
            ->createQueryBuilder('domainNic')
            ->join('domainNic.article', 'article')
            ->andWhere('article.category = :domainCategory')
            ->setParameter('domainCategory', Article::CATEGORY_DOMAINS)
            ->orderBy('article.title');
```

My form type definition below looks like this:

```
$builder->add(
            'withTld',
            'bootstrap_collection',
            array(
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'add_button_text' => 'addtext',
                'delete_button_text' => 'deletetext',
                'type' => 'entity',
                'sub_widget_col'  => 5,
                'label' => '***',
                'options' => array(
                    'class' => 'Namespace\Entity\Domain\NIC',
                    'query_builder' => $qb,
                    'property' => 'title'
                )
            )
        );
```

The result looks exactly as expected, but for every found record, Symfony doesn't use the data from the QueryBuilder. Instead, Symfony fetches the title for each record again.

Anybody knows a solution? I want Symfony to use the data from the QueryBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an extra `select` line in you query builder:

```
$qb = $this
    ->em
    ->getRepository('Namespace\Entity\Domain\Nic')
    ->createQueryBuilder('domainNic')

    ->addSelect('article') // <---------------- THIS

    ->join('domainNic.article', 'article')
    ->andWhere('article.category = :domainCategory')
    ->setParameter('domainCategory', Article::CATEGORY_DOMAINS)
    ->orderBy('article.title');
```